# Does the "Copy the login credentials ..." button copy to the stackexchange.com site?

Tags: support, profile-copying

The reason why I'm asking this is: I've got two openids associated with my accounts. I do have a third one which I did use in the past, before SE became an openid provider.

On all of my accounts, I've got the SE openid as primary and another one as secondary (yes, I did see this changed very recently, but it doesn't influence my question).

Whenever I log in to the SE site, I'm allowed to use any of those three accounts. When logging out, it shows two openids associated with that account, the one I used as secondary openid, and the third one I haven't been using for a long time.

My question is: Why does using the "Copy login credentials..." button have no effect? Upon using it, I'd expect to see the two openids I generally use being copied to the SE site as well, but this doesn't seem to be the case.